# Django 3 delete field items via Admin panel

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django app, in which i have a model of Candidate, and the candidate has a field Video - goes as file.

I do have the option to change the field, for example upload a new video, and it will replace it, but how can i delete a video of a candidate, and leave it empty?

currntly i have something like this in the admin panel:

```
Currently: uploads/VIDEOS/mediarecorder_11.mp4
Change: [Coose File] No file chosen
```

how can i just delete the video, and leave it empty?

as you can see in this image - https://ibb.co/FxsGRfq
I don't get a 'clear' option or something..

Candidate class:

class Candidate(models.Model):

```
....
video = models.FileField(upload_to=f'uploads/VIDEOS', null=True, blank=True, validators=[video_size_validator],
                         editable=True)

cv = models.FileField(upload_to=f'uploads/CV', null=True, validators=[cv_size_validator])

...
```

Comment: Added the model

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `clear` option on the same line as currently, check it and save your object.

Comment: There is no clear option, unfortunately - i also have a field of CV, and its also the same, they both look like this when there is a file https://ibb.co/FxsGRfq

Comment: As an option you can also try creating a helper model `CandidateVideo` with a `title`, `file` and a `ForeignKey` or `OneToOne` referencing your `Candidate` model, then you can just remove that object as a whole.

Comment: Not the exact solution I'm looking for, I just need to lean some items, and wondering if there a way to do it via the admin panel or something.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if there's a way to do it with the admin interface but you could also write a helper `view` to do it, like `user = User.objects.get(pk=pk) | user.video = None | user.save()`

Comment: Well, that also sounds like an option I guess, thanks!

Comment: btw if you decide to use my first solution you can add multiple `videos` or `cvs` for the same `candidate` so consider it as it is a better one.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, but there is no need for it at this point, not what the client asked for, but I will take it to my consideration on the next project!